# How can I give a plugin's default settings access to the final settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a jQuery plugin. When the plugin runs, the first thing it does is determine its settings. It does this by taking some default settings and overriding some or all of them with whatever the user passed in.

Here's a simplified version:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.somePlugin = function(userOptions) {
    // Short name for internal use - exposed below for external modification
    var defaults = $.fn.somePlugin.defaults;

    // Decide settings
    // User settings overrule defaults, but merge both into an empty 
    // hash so that original defaults hash isn't modified
    var settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, userOptions);

    settings.alerter.call();

    // More code, etc.
  }

  $.fn.somePlugin.defaults = {
    name: 'Captain Slappy von Martinez, Esquire, DDS',
    favoriteColor: 'red',
    alerter: function(){alert("I got bones!");}        
  }
  
})( jQuery );
```

So, if you call the plugin like this:

```
    $('div').somePlugin({alerter: function(){alert('No bones here!');}});
```

... you override the default `alerter` function, but use the default `favoriteColor`.

I'm defining the defaults outside the plugin itself so that they are publicly accessible. So if you want to change the **default** value for `favoriteColor`, you can just do this:

```
$.fn.somePlugin.defaults.favoriteColor = 'blue';
```

... and that will change it for every instance on the page after that.

All of this works fine.

Here's my problem: in one of the default functions, I need to refer to `settings`. Something like this:

```
  $.fn.somePlugin.defaults = {
    name: 'Captain Slappy von Martinez, Esquire, DDS',
    favoriteColor: 'red',
    alerter: function(){alert("Paint me " + settings.favoriteColor);}        
  }
```

But when I try this, I get a Javascript error on the line where the default alerter function is declared: "settings is not defined." True enough: it's not defined yet when the parser hits that line. It WILL be defined by the time the function runs, but that doesn't seem to matter.

So my question is: **How can I import my default function into the plugin in such a way that it has access to `settings`?**

- Is there a way to delay evaluation of `settings` until the function is actually called?
- If so, is there a way to make sure it has access to the local scope of the plugin, even though I assume that, as an object, this function is being passed by reference? I know that I can alter the value of `this` inside a function by using `someFunction.call(valueToUseForThis)`, but I don't know whether I can alter its scope after the fact.

### Some Stuff that Doesn't Work

- Initially, it seemed that if I declared `settings` in the outer, self-executing function, that would make it available to the defaults. But declaring it there causes problems: if I use my plugin multiple times on a page, the instances get their settings mixed up.

Comment: One workaround I thought of is to store `settings` on the DOM with `jQuery.data`, but I'm hoping that there's a more elegant solution that will also teach me more about Javascript.

Comment: I like to use this plugin format (http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/) because it stores a reverse reference to the DOM object (using jQuery.data as you implied in the above comment). So you can simply get your setting using something like `$(el).data('somePlugin').options.favoriteColor`. You can read a bit more about this design pattern here (http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-plugin-design-patterns-part-i/).

Comment: @fudgey - wow, that is a VERY cool tool. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any attempts to change scope after the fact are doomed. There's no dynamic scoping in JavaScript.

**Workaround 1.**
Pass settings to the alerter explicitly:

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function(userOptions) {
  var settings = $.extend(...);
  settings.alerter(settings)
}

$.fn.somePlugin.defaults = {
  favoriteColor: 'red',
  alerter: function(settings) { alert("Paint me " + settings.favoriteColor) }
}
```

**Workaround 2.** Pass settings to the alerter implicitly:

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function(userOptions) {
  var settings = $.extend(...);
  settings.alerter()
}

$.fn.somePlugin.defaults = {
  favoriteColor: 'red',
  alerter: function() { alert("Paint me " + this.favoriteColor) }
}
```

Both solutions tested and work well with multiple uses of the plugin. If you have no plans for using `this` keyword in your alerter, you can use it for referencing settings.

**The third valid solution**, which you and fudgey mentioned, is to attach settings object to the DOM element itself:

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function(userOptions) {
  var settings = $.extend(...);
  $(this).data('somePlugin', {settings: settings})
  settings.alerter.call(this)
}

$.fn.somePlugin.defaults = {
  favoriteColor: 'red',
  alerter: function() {
      alert("Paint me " + $(this).data('somePlugin').settings.favoriteColor)
  }
}
```

---

Extra fun. Emulating dynamic scope, **a.k.a don't do this**

```
function dynamic(fn) {
  var parts = fn.toString().split('{')
  fn = parts.shift() + '{ with (args) { ' + parts.join('{') + '}'
  return {bind: function(args) { return eval('(' + fn + ')') }}
}

a = b = c = 0

function adder(c) {
  alert(a + b + c)
}

dynamic(adder).bind({a: 1, b: 2})(3) // alert(6)
```

Usage in a plugin:

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function(userOptions) {
  var settings = $.extend(...);
  dynamic(settings.alerter).bind({settings: settings})()
}

$.fn.somePlugin.defaults = {
  favoriteColor: 'red',
  alerter: function() { alert("Paint me " + settings.favoriteColor) }
}
```

Comment: +1 - I was just about to post an equivalent to your second workaround as a solution when I spotted your answer.

Comment: @Luke, I just came up with an impractical, but interesting solution. See extra section.

Comment: Nice! If a little impractical like you say!

Comment: I will have to do some studying to understand your "emulating dynamic scope" example, but I'm satisfied that passing settings explicitly is the best solution in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan, this last example works by converting the original function to string, wrapping the function's body in "with(args) {...}" construct, and then converting it back to function. The "with" keyword is used to bind function's variables to the settings object. The final function is like this: function() { with(args) { alert("Paint me " + settings.favoriteColor) }}, where args is a reference to the settings object. Actually, it's more simple than it sounds.

Comment: On an unrelated note, consider giving me that nice bounty.

Comment: You get the bounty! Sorry I hadn't awarded it sooner - I had assumed that all I had to do was accept your answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The `settings` variable is scoped to the `$.fn.somePlugin` function so it is not available outside of this, which is where you're trying to reference it in `$.fn.somePlugin.defaults`. Can you not simply move the default object inside `$.fn.somePlugin` and declare it in there?

Try this (code untested):

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.somePlugin = function(userOptions) {
    // Short name for internal use - exposed below for external modification
    var settings = {},
        defaults = {
            name: 'Captain Slappy von Martinez, Esquire, DDS',
            favoriteColor: 'red',
            alerter: function(){alert("Paint me " + settings.favoriteColor);}        
        };

    // Decide settings
    // User settings overrule defaults, but merge both into an empty 
    // hash so that original defaults hash isn't modified
    settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, userOptions);

    settings.alerter.call();

    // More code, etc.
  }

})( jQuery );
```

**Edit**: In light of your comment below, the simplest approach is probably to just move the declaration of settings up a level into the outer function - being locally scoped to this function, it will still be private to external callers. Revised code below:

```
(function( $ ) {

  var settings = {}

  $.fn.somePlugin = function(userOptions) {
    // Decide settings
    // User settings overrule defaults, but merge both into an empty 
    // hash so that original defaults hash isn't modified
    settings = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.somePlugin.defaults, userOptions);

    settings.alerter.call();

    // More code, etc.
  }

  $.fn.somePlugin.defaults = {
      name: 'Captain Slappy von Martinez, Esquire, DDS',
      favoriteColor: 'red',
      alerter: function(){alert("Paint me " + settings.favoriteColor);}        
  }

})( jQuery );

$.fn.somePlugin.defaults.favoriteColor = 'blue';

$.fn.somePlugin(); // Should alert 'Paint me blue'

alert(settings.favoriteColour) // Will not work here;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said this: I'm defining the defaults outside the plugin so that they're publicly accessible. See updated question.

Comment: I have revised my answer for you :)

Comment: Well. That certainly solves my problem in a forehead-slappingly simple way. :)

Comment: Oops - it turns out that this actually creates another problem for me: even if I'm not referencing `settings` in the defaults, declaring settings outside the plugin scope, even though it's inside the self-executing outer function, somehow creates conflict between multiple uses of the plugin on the same page. I'll have to look for another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change `settings` to `this`:

```
$.fn.somePlugin.defaults = {
    name: 'Captain Slappy von Martinez, Esquire, DDS',
    favoriteColor: 'red',
    alerter: function () { alert("Paint me " + this.favoriteColor); }        
}
```

That's it!

**EDIT:** Oh!  I just noticed something in your code!  Don't use `.call()` to call `settings.alerter`.  That changes the meaning of `this`.  Just call the method directly.  If you *must* use `.call()`, pass in `settings` as the parameter for `this`.

```
settings.alerter.call();         // this won't work.
settings.alerter();              // but this will!
settings.alerter.call(settings); // this works too
```

Here's a complete working example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/k2Eep/2/

Comment: Which doesn't work because 'this' points to window in your example. You'll have to change it to settings.alerter.call(settings), which I addressed in my answer.

Comment: @Alexey - Nope, `this` points to the object that the method is a member of.  It works, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/k2Eep/

Comment: Put it into the code in question and you'll see that it doesn't work. Because Nathan is calling the alerter with settings.alerter.call(). To make your code work he'll either have to change it to settings.alerter.call(settings) or simply to settings.alerter()

Comment: @Alexey - Doh! You beat me too it.  I just noticed that as well, and updated my answer.